# How can I parse Annotations with Olingo?

Tags: java, odata, olingo

My Java application uses SAP's repackaged Olingo library for v2 OData services, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cds.repackaged/odata-v2-lib, to parse the metadata.xml document of an OData service:

```java
Edm parsedMetadata = EntityProvider.readMetadata(inputStream, true);
```

I do this to analyze the available entities and associations, and it works fine. However, the metadata document also contains `<Annotations>` that I am interested in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx ...>
    <edmx:Reference ... /></edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices ...>
        <Schema ...>
            <EntityType .../>
            ...
            <ComplexType ...>...</ComplexType>
            ...
            <Association ...>...</Association>
            ...
            <Annotations ...>...</Annotations>     <!-- I want these here -->
            ...
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Olingo's `Edm` object provides all sorts of getters for the different parts, like entity types, complex types, and associations, but none for annotations. I also didn't find any other classes in Olingo that would support me in retrieving them.

Is there a possibility to get these Annotations details via Olingo, too? If not, are there other possibilities how I could get these?

Answer (score 0):

They are available at the EntityContainer level

You can retieve them like this

```
Edm parsedMetadata = EntityProvider.readMetadata(con.getInputStream(), true);

EdmAnnotations annotations = parsedMetadata.getDefaultEntityContainer().getAnnotations();
```

Or if you have multiple containers or want to use the named API it would be

```
EdmAnnotations annotations = parsedMetadata.getEntityContainer("SomeName").getAnnotations();
```

Otherwise on all the properties there is a `getAnnotations` method but then you'll have to loop over all the properties and consolidate the annotations

For example

```
for (EdmEntitySet e : parsedMetadata.getEntitySets() ){
        EdmAnnotations annotations = e.getAnnotations();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the annotations aren't available there, neither from the default entity container, nor from the individual entities and properties.  getAnnotations() provides me a list of annotation attributes, i.e. the additional properties that are contained within <property ...> tags. However, the annotation elements list, where I'd expect the extra annotations I'm looking for, is always empty...

Comment: Do you have any publicly accessible Service metadata, which has annotations? I tested with https://services.odata.org/ but only OData Services 3 and above, have annotations in them, and olingo client sees the metadata and errors out in that case. Maybe OData 3 was what brought annotations. If you are at SAP, there is a team who contributes to Olingo, maybe they can tell the expected behaviors